# Best network structure for unsupervised learning

Tags: nlp, unsupervised-learning

Currently using networkX to build a probability based network for unsupervised learning, it is a basic reader understanding relational connectivity through probabilities, network slows significantly after about 40 pages (8000 words) any suggestions for a better network platform would be much appreciated.

Comment: I do not vote for closing because your potential question sounds interesting but at the moment it's pretty unclear and fuzzy so please revise it and care about the structure and clarity. What do u mean by Network? What do u mean by "network slows significantly after about 40 pages"? Do u want to cluster readers based on their interest or what? What is "reader understanding relational connectivity"? and please also check and modify the structure of question again. Proper usage of dots and question marks help people to help you.

Comment: Thanks Kasra, I will modify and try to clarify what I am working on, more to come

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a problem that can be solved with Probabilistic Graphical Models (PGMs). PGMs use graphs to expresses the conditional dependence structure between random variables.

[pgmpy](https://github.com/pgmpy/pgmpy) is a Python package for PGMs.